# Gradient on multiple icons

Tags: css, gradient

Is there any way to set gradient on multiple icons like on [this image](https://res.cloudinary.com/db20zgpmk/image/upload/v1520799691/Screenshot_2018-03-11_22.20.03.png)?

Here's [my codepen](https://codepen.io/avalan4e/pen/gwpryq?editors=1100) for the case

> HTML

```
<div class="stars">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

> SCSS

```
.stars {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FEDD54, #FD9667);
  width: fit-content;
  i {
    // color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-webkit-background-clip` and position a fixed-size `gradient` on each icon individually, but it currently browser support for this is limited to Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

*Minor gotcha: Firefox doesn't have a `-moz-background-clip` variant but recognizes the `-webkit-` prefix instead.*

```
.stars {

  width: fit-content;
  i {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FEDD54, #FD9667);
    background-size: 100% 5em;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }

  i:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-position: 0 1em;
  }
  i:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-position: 0 2em;
  }
  i:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-position: 0 3em;
  }
  i:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-position: 0 4em;
  }
  i:nth-of-type(5) {
    background-position: 0 5em;
  }
}
```

Depending on the effect you want to achieve, the easiest way might be to create the whole row of icons as a background image and use `width` to display the number of icons needed.

Comment: That's just awesome! As for easy background variant I'm not sure I do understand you. Isn't it just the same as adding icons explicitly? I mean they're still of black color on gradient background if I do smth like `background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/db20zgpmk/image/upload/v1520801867/star_1.svg), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FEDD54, #FD9667);`

Comment: I mean draw the stars on a .png or something, then use that image file as background - if you give the background a fixed width and size the element to be smaller than the background, it will effectively crop off the last N stars from the image. The individual stars won't be selectable, clickable or anything though.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do, is to determinate some breakpoints. For exemple, if you have 3 icons, i'd take 2 colors for each icons and then set a specific gradient for each one of them.

Another solution would be to set a general background gradient, the set the icon transparents and cover it back with a white background except over the icons. I know they're css tricks for doing stuff like that, but can't remember where i did find them :/

Anyway the first solution is so far the easiest one.

Comment: The second variant is just what I thought about possible solution. The only problem is I also have no idea how to do that trick. But the first variant is nice indeed. Still I hope someone will bring us a more beautiful hack. Thank you much for the idea.